# How to read csv file in Xslt to transform it into CDATA tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to write an XSLT that will read a CSV file and transform the data into CDATA tag

sample input file

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
apple,mango,orange
```

required output

```
<![CDATA[apple|mango|orange]]>
```

Comment: As you are using XSLT 2.0, read up on the unparsed-text function (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unparsed-text) to start with, followed by perhaps tokenize (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) or replace (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"...>

<xsl:template name="main">
  <out>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('input.csv'), '\n')">
    <line>
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ',')" separator="|"/>
    </line>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </out>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="line"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i get the below message in the XML output file Cannot locate :  ..i mentioned the absolute path for the file in the function unparsed-text('C:/test.csv') still the same error message can you please let me know how i can fix this issue .. its really urgent .Thnks

Comment: You haven't given the error message. What can't it locate? The function unparsed-text()? The file? And please note, telling people who try to help you that it's urgent is a real turn-off - we don't want to help people who are in a hurry, because it usually means they are spending less time thinking about the answers.

Comment: It occurs to me you probably aren't using XSLT 2.0 at all, and just mis-tagged your question.

Comment: Hi Micheal i apologies for asking it as urgent ..Really appreciate you help .

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:template name="main">
  <out>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('file:///I:/Documents/XmlSpyWorkSpace/Test.csv'), '\n')">
    <line>
      <xsl:value-of select="fn:tokenize(., ',')" separator="|"/>
    </line>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </out>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="line"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I get the below Message in the output file   Cannot locate :

Comment: Is "Cannot locate" the entire error message? If so, I would try a different XSLT processor, you're likely to get better diagnostics.

Comment: Yes Cannot Locate is the entire ERROR message i am using Altova XML spy IDE

Comment: Try it with Saxon. If one tool gives you bad diagnostics it's often good to try another.

Comment: Hi Micheal ,, i tried with Saxon and its working as expected .. thank You very much and appreciative your help